# Save in a external file the dataset obtained from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can I save in a external file the dataset obtained from `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory()`?

```
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing

train_ds = preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = 'aclImdb/train',
    validation_split= 0.2,
    subset= 'training', # Estamos en training
    shuffle = True,
    seed= 689
)

val_ds = preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = 'aclImdb/train',
    validation_split= 0.2,
    subset= 'validation',
    shuffle = True,
    seed= 689
)

test_ds = preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = 'aclImdb/test'
)
```

I'm reading the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text_dataset_from_directory) but I'm not sure if it's possible.

---

**Answer to @Lescurel question**

I want to do this because I want to avoid do this preprocessing each time and have to wait while its done. And furthermore, because I want to see if this new saved file is takes up less space in my computer.

Actually, I don't care the format. I thought that if this can be done, it would already have a standard format that everyone uses.

---

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you elaborate? In what format do you want to save the dataset, and for what reasons?

Comment: @Lescurel I have answered in the question itself! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Technically that is possible.

But you don't want that, because:
The `preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory` create a generator based dataset, that supports

- on the fly loading of data,
- shuffle after each epoch (for training),
- prefetching and other features.

If you just save a shuffled dataset as file on your computer, you will have to do it again. If the dataset would be/get larger than your RAM you would have to care about that, too.

If you still want to do it: You can get the batches of data with dataset.take(1) and then either save all individual string (using `for .. in`) or pickle to write the binary objects... But I repeat myself: You do not want to do that.

If you want to do preprocessing up front, use a program that works on your text files and saves them as text files back again (e.g. for cleaning etc.) - but be aware that you will have to do the same for test and production data later on, so everything you remove from the (keras) pipeline, you have to care about yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure if I want it or not, was an idea and want to know if the other people do it or not. So, thank you very much for your explanation. :)